# How to inject a LifecycleOwner in Android using Dagger2?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-lifecycle

I happen to have an Android lifecycle aware component with the following interface:

```
class MyLifecycleAwareComponent @Inject constructor(
    private val: DependencyOne,
    private val: DependencyTwo
) {

    fun bindToLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

All Dagger specific components and modules are configured correctly and have been working great so far.

In each activity when I need to use the component I do the following:

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var component: MyLifecycleAwareComponent

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        component.bindToLifecycleOwner(this)
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to get rid of `bindLifecycleOwner` and denote my component like this:

```
class MyLifecycleAwareComponent @Inject constructor(
    private val: DependencyOne,
    private val: DependencyTwo,
    private val: LifecycleOwner
) {
    ...
}
```

And provide the `lifecycleOwner` within the scope of individual activities (which implement the interface by extending `AppCompatActivity`).

Is there any way to do it with Dagger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may bind your Activity to LifecycleOwner from your ActivityModule:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {
    ...
    @Binds
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun bindLifecycleOwner(activity: AppCompatActivity): LifecycleOwner
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the viewlifecycleowner of a fragment?